# Парсинг видео в вк через api (iframe)

Tags: php, iframe, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Как парсить видео в вк через api в iframe-приложении с помощью серверного языка (php) методом video.get ?

Answer (score 1):

1. Методом video.get ничего парсить не надо, к этому методу нужно обращаться.
2. [Описание video.get](https://vk.com/dev/video.get), что он возвращает - написано в разделе "Результат" этой страницы. Как и любой другой метод, он упаковывает данные в JSON. Разбор этих данных в PHP делается при помощи функци [json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php). Что-то непонятно уже на этом этапе, или до, или после?

Comment: беда в том что это не серверный метод, как данные в json получать я знаю, все несколько сложнее.

Comment: Тогда опишите проблему так, как её видите вы. И чтобы было понятно другим. Я - не вижу ни малейшей, во всяком случае вызвать метод video.get из iframe-приложения, передать полученные данные ajax-запросом на свой сервер, отпарсить там, получить и вывести результат.

Comment: хорошо, это нужно делать каждые 20 минут, то есть через крон, то есть ajax там не нужен, только сервер.

Comment: То есть у вас есть iframe-приложение, которое на самом деле не iframe, но вы хотите чтобы оно вело себя как iframe, так, что ли?